# PHPStorm: reformat long comments

Tags: ide, phpstorm

How do I reformat long (doc) comments in my code? Hitting "reformat" doesn't work. For example when I have this in my code:

```
/**
 * Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin porta ac urna quis sagittis. Nam risus leo, ultricies 
 * id ante sed, bibendum rutrum diam. 
 * Suspendisse viverra dui et ligula aliquet, sit amet mattis magna consequat. Morbi venenatis tempus mattis. 
 * Praesent mollis quam non turpis laoreet placerat.
 */
```

How do I turn it into this?

```
/**
 * Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin porta ac urna quis sagittis. Nam risus leo, ultricies 
 * id ante sed, bibendum rutrum diam. Suspendisse viverra dui et ligula aliquet, sit amet mattis magna consequat. Morbi
 * venenatis tempus mattis. Praesent mollis quam non turpis laoreet placerat.
 */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such functionality is not currently available in PhpStorm.

But you may try **Wrap to Column plugin** -- it may do OK for you (seems to work -- based on very quick test).

---

Related tickets:

- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-374
- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-3713
- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-13469
- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-18264